# How can i pass dynamic variables/secrets while deploying container image on Azure Webapp through Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying docker image and wants to modify some of the application settings at runtime. I am using Azure DevOps for build and release of my docker image.

**Build Pipeline:** Able to create build image with default application settings.

**Release pipeline:** Wants to deploy build image with updated application settings. (wants to modify some of the variables)

Is this feasible? What can be the best approach of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create library variables with the values you want to set:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

After that, you'll be able to retrieve the values by using:

```
$(customer)
```

I recommend you to store the content of the secrets into Azure Key Vault, and retrieve the secrets from there (also using library variables).

Lastly, all you need to do is get those values and set your app service settings (I do this through a powershell task):

```
$myResourceGroup = 'PartsUnlimitedMRP'
$mySite = 'centpartsunlimited'

$webApp = Get-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $mySite -Slot production
$appSettingList = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings

$hash = @{}
ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingList) {
    $hash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
}

$hash['customer'] = $(customer)

Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $mySite -AppSettings $hash -Slot production
```

Comment: Thanks @Thiago. I was also thinking the same way. Just have one doubt, if publishing variables like key vault URL in Azure web app service application setting is best practice?

Comment: there's no problem because only the managed identity of your function will be able to access it (and the others you grant access)